# How to remove duplicate variables in JSON

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mariadb

I have the command:

```
SELECT JSON_MERGE_PATCH ('{"variable": "1", "variable": "2", "anothervariable": "another"}', '{"variable": "3"}')
```

However, this query generates a result:

```
{"variable": "3", "variable": "3", "anothervariable": "another"}
```

I need a result without duplicates:

```
{"variable": "3", "anothervariable": "another"}
```

How could this be arranged, please?

On fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=57b13797114fecc96aa2b24b5f5e02d4

How could the result be arranged without duplication?
The order of JSONs in the query cannot be changed.

Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Try [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=87897b68145b8de8b3f842ea16216d20).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT JSON_MERGE_PATCH ('{"variable": "3"}', '{"variable": "1", "variable": "2", "anothervariable": "another"}')
```

Comment: Hello, thanks, but not working. This querry return wrong result: "{"variable": "1", "anothervariable": "another"}" But, i need get result:
 "{"variable": "3", "anothervariable": "another"}"

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Comment: The order of JSONs in the query cannot be changed.

The point is that this solution overwrites the wrong value of the variable. variable = 1, but I need the value with the highest priority value = 3 there. By swapping JSONs in the query, the user adjusted the priority of the variables.  The JSON that is at the end has a higher priority when merge_patch. So I need a solution that will really solve the problem so that variable = 3 is returned.

Comment: There is no order in a JSON. Its random in which order the items inside appear. So you will have no chance to get the right one every time. Even if you find a way to make it work on your computer, on an other computer with a different JSON decoder it can look completely different. Make you JSN valid where you create it, don't try to fix errors done before

Comment: So the json_merge function is unusable because it connects randomly? :-) I don't understand what my computer has in common, I don't really understand you at all. How i can resolve my problem? I have N pieces of JSONs, I want to merge them so that one of them has a higher priority in case of duplication of variables.